# Error when launch Eclipse in Ubuntu using terminal

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Eclipse-platform in my Ubuntu machine. I have tried to launch Eclipse in using command "eclispe" in terminal. But it showing following error message. Please assist.

Error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Eclipse:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/ubuntu/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1527494671231.log.
```

Comment: My java version is    openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: See the log file /home/ubuntu/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1527494671231.log.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `/home/ubuntu/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1527494671231.log`? Thanks.